# Simplify hypergeometric function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, summation

> **Theorem:** *Let* $H_n$ *be the* $nth$ *harmonic number. Then*
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} H_n x^n=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\log\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2\sqrt{1-4x}} \bigg)$$

How can I simplify following hypergeometric function by using *Mathematica*?

```
Sum[Binomial[2 n, n] HarmonicNumber[n] x^n, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

[image]

I tried `FullSimplify` and `FunctionExpand`  but it doesn't work

Comment: For what it's worth, `-Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1/2, 1, 1, 4*x]` looks completely different from `2/Sqrt[1 - 4*x]*Log[(1 - Sqrt[1 - 4*x])/(2*Sqrt[1 - 4*x])]` when I plot it. Are you sure that theorem is correct?

Comment: @Pillsy I think its correct. [see here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL19/Chen/chen21.pdf) page 3.

Comment: @Pillsy, you have a misplaced "-" in the numerator of the Log[ ] term. Plots OK after you fix that.

Comment: @MikeY so I have. thanks!

Comment: *Mathematica* is not yet that good at simplifying parameter derivatives of hypergeometric functions, much less recognizing them to be elementary. (The general expressions are horrendous; see e.g. [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/42/39/395208).)

Comment: Plot of the real and imaginary parts of the functions appear identical: `Plot[Evaluate@ReIm[#[x]], {x, -10, 10},
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{Re, Im}, {0.2, 0.8}],
    Exclusions -> {1/4},
    PlotLabel -> Style[#, 14, Bold],
    ImageSize -> 360] & /@ {sum, f} // Column`